# If greater than or equal in MIPS

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips, equals

Prompt for and input two integers “a” and “b” using syscalls

Display one of the following statements depending on if a>b, or a=b or a

- You entered a greater than b
- You entered an equal to b
- You entered a less than b

I have to get this prompt and I tried so hard to get it done. This is where I'm stucked, I'd really appreciate your help.

```
    .data  
p1: .asciiz "Please enter the first number ? "  
p2: .asciiz " Please enter the second number? "  
ans1: .asciiz " \nYou entered a greater than b "  
ans2: .asciiz " \nYou entered a equal to b "  
ans3: .asciiz " \nYou entered a less than b "  


        .text
        .globl main

main:    
    li $v0, 4     #system call code for print_str  
    la $a0, p1  #address of string to print  
    syscall     #print the first prompt  


    li $v0, 5   #system call code for read_int
    syscall     #read first integer
    move $t1, $v0   #store it till later

    li $v0, 4   #system call code for print_str
    la $a0, p2  #address of string to print
    syscall     #prints the second prompt

    li $v0, 5   #system call code for read_int
    syscall     #read first integer
    move $t2, $v0   #store it till later

    slt $t1,$s1,$s0      # checks if $s0 > $s1
    beq $t1,1,label1
```

I really don't know how to use branch statements, and it's really confusing. I would like to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you read the numbers into `$t1` and `$t2` then compare `$s1` and `$s0`? Where is it confusing?

Simply use `slt` and `beq`/`bne`, that'll cover all comparison cases you need.

Suppose a is in `$s0`, b is in `$s1`

- a < b:

  ```
  slt $t0, $s0, $s1
  bne $t0, $zero, a_lt_b # $t0 == 1 != 0 if a < b
  ```
- a = b:

  ```
  beq $s0, $s1, a_eq_b   # nothing more to explain
  ```
- a > b:

  ```
  slt $t0, $s1, $s0
  bne $t0, $zero, b_lt_a # $t0 == 1 != 0 if b < a
  ```
- a >= b:

  ```
  slt $t0, $s0, $s1
  beq $t0, $zero, a_ge_b # $t0 == 0 if a >= b or !(a < b)
  ```
- a <= b:

  ```
  slt $t0, $s1, $s0
  beq $t0, $zero, b_ge_a # $t0 == 0 if b >= a or !(b < a)
  ```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer I guess. But I really appreciate your time and help. Thank you so much