# Inequality in MIPS

Tags: mips, inequality, inequalities

May I ask if I have gotten it right for the following inequality equivalent in MIPS? Or is there any better way to implement with the basic commands of slt and bne and bqe?

```
less than <
slt $t0, $s1, $s2
beq $t0, $zero, L
  ....
L:

less than equals <=
addi $s2, $s2, 1
slt $t0, $s1, $s2
beq $t0, $zero, L
   ....
L:

greater than >
slt $t0, $s1, $s2
bne $t0, $zero, L
  ....
L:

greater than equals >=
addi $s2, $s2, 1
slt $t0, $s1, $s2
bne $s0, $zero, L
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859471/if-greater-than-or-equal-in-mips

Comment: _"[have I] gotten it right?"_ Well, does it produce the desired result?

Comment: @Michael I think so, but I am can't be sure~

Comment: Why not? Just run it in a simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Comment: @Michael Yeah! Thanks why didn't I think of that!